# A question about conditional replacement

Tags: programming, conditional

```
{g[x, y, z], h[x, y], f[]} /. (f_[t___] /; f != List) :> Plus[t]
```

Why is the output of this expression

```
{g[x, y, z], h[x, y], f[]}
```

instead of

```
{x+y+z,x+y,0}
```

When I change the code to

```
{g[x, y, z], h[x, y], f[]} /. (f_[t___] /; f =!= List) :> Plus[t]
```

everything works as I expected

Comment: This has been answered before. It is the same as the difference between `SameQ` and `Equal`. Instead of repeating things, please see this [difference-between-and-in-mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286736/difference-between-and-in-mathematica)  which talks about the difference between SameQ and Equal. This applies exactly to `UnSameQ` and `Unequal`.

Comment: Somehow this input looks familiar.

Comment: I will add to Nasser's comment, that, for the purposes of pattern-matching, every pattern condition that does not explicitly evaluate to `True`, is considered `False`. `Equal` does not evaluate, so there is no match. All these bits can actually also be found in the book (but not in one place), although perhaps I could have elaborated more on this particular example you picked.