# Bug in grouping after editing code?

Tags: front-end, bugs, parsing, precedence

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0**

---

While looking at [A question about conditional replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64661/121) I think I discovered a bug in the Front End that affects both 7.0.1 and 10.0.1 under Windows.

If I copy and paste this line into a new Cell in a Notebook:

```
{g[x, y, z], h[x, y], f[]} /. (f_[t___] /; f != List) :> Plus[t]
```

then select `≠` (auto-converted to single character) and type over it `=!=` and evaluate I get:

> ```
> {g[x, y, z], h[x, y], f[]}
> ```

Rather than the expected:

> ```
> {x + y + z, x + y, 0}
> ```

If I use menu **Cell** > **Convert To** > **InputForm** the input cell is converted to:

```
{g[x, y, z], h[x, y], f[]} /. ((f_)[t___] /; f) =!= List :> Plus[t]
```

Note the parentheses: `((f_)[t___] /; f)` is grouped separately from `=!= List`.  The RHS therefore evaluates to:

> ```
> True :> +t
> ```

Does this problem affect all recent versions on all platforms or is it more localized?

Comment: reproduced in V9.0.1.0 (windows 8)

Comment: Reproduces in versions 8.0.4 and 10.0.1 under Win7 x64. Instead of converting the `Cell` to `InputForm` I just add `//Hold` at the end of the expression and evaluate it again.

Comment: Strangely enough, if you add a space _anywhere_ before or after `=!=`, or edit anything else inside the parantheses, it gives the expected output.

Comment: After you substituted `=!=` you can simply go left of the `f` and press Ctrl+. for expand selection. You see that the front-end parses it incorrectly because `/;` seems to have a higher precedence. Weird. Btw, M8.0.4 on OSX.

Comment: Yep.  Reproduced 10.0.1.0 on Mac OS X.

Comment: @halirutan As I think you know I am [well aware of that method.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/using-a-list-of-tuples-in-a-pure-function/3146#3146)  I chose Shift+Ctrl+I in this case because the result was easier to display in my question, and because the actual insertion of parentheses indicates that grouping is non-standard.  Thanks for the report, BTW. ;)

Comment: Persists in 10.4.1

Comment: Do you think http://i.stack.imgur.com/smo9Z.gif is the same bug or would it be worth opening a separate post for this? (Looking at `InputForm`, in the first line there's actually a `(a/*b)@*c`.) This was on Mathematica 11.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think when you press `=` over `≠`, the underlying `RowBox`-es got re-grouped (which is a correct move), but somehow didn't re-group again when finishing input `=!=`. I don't know if the FrontEnd is supposed to re-parse code every 1/n second, but it does look like a bug to me.

One possible workaround: Select the cell, from the **Edit** menu, **Copy As** **Plain Text**, paste in to an empty Input Cell. This should enforce re-parsing the code.

Comment: ... yet another work-around: type `=!=` in the order `!=`+ backspace + backspace `=` :)

Comment: @kguler Or can we enforce an in-place re-parsing on the Cell? :)

Comment: Actually, retyping of any character to the left of `=!=` inside `(f_ ... List)` seems to force re-parsing.

Comment: @kguler Yes I saw [your comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64665/bug-in-grouping-after-editing-code/64667?noredirect=1#comment181360_64665) :) Off topic: sometimes I wonder why human write code in plain text and ask for a parser to analyse/formalize it. It's unnatural ...